# How to generate random numbers in C with an appropriate spacing?

Tags: c, random

I had to generate a given number of float random values in the range [1,10] for some code. However, due to some constraints, the spacing between the random numbers has to be at least dx(given).

I'm using code blocks. `(float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX/(10))` generates random numbers in the range.

Now, to achieve the desired spacing as said earlier, any suggestions for a simple strategy easily implementable in C?

Comment: Can you give an example of "dx"? Generate an integer in the range of `[1, 10/dx]` and then multiply by `dx` to get a floating point number. @edit 
`dx was a number, say 0.1 ` So generate a number say `[1,100]` and divide by `10`?

Comment: `1 + (1 + rand() % ((10 - 1) / dx)) / 10.0`

Comment: After each random number, the range (originally [1...10]) reduces by 2*dx (aside from edge cases).  Generate the next random number in reduced range and then find where it fits in [1...10].  simple? --> it is some work

Comment: my bad...yea...that's a neat way...Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Another way... generate `n` evenly spaced values and make a random adjustment to each, in the range of say, `±(interval - dx) / 2`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this without bias is to keep generating random numbers until they satisfy the criteria:

```c
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>


bool check_spacing(float* of, size_t count, float spacing) {
    // n^2 algorithm, but can be reduced to n lg n if you sort and then just compare to
    // previous item and either allocate a copy to sort or shuffle afterwards
    for (size_t i = 1; i < count; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
            if (fabsf(of[i] - of[j]) <= spacing) return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

void generate_until_spacing(float* to, size_t count, float spacing, float rng(void*), void* context) {
    do {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) to[i] = rng(context);
    } while (!check_spacing(to, count, spacing));
}

float frng(void* context) {
    // Your original rng should have looked like `1 + rand() / (RAND_MAX / 9f)`
    // for range [1, 10], or `rand() / (RAND_MAX / 10f)` for range [0, 10]
    float* min_max = context;
    float min = min_max[0];
    float max = min_max[1];
    return min + (rand() / (RAND_MAX / (max - min)));
}

int main(void) {
    srand(time(NULL));

    float spacing = 0.2;
    float min = 1;
    float max = 10;

    float numbers[10];
    generate_until_spacing(numbers, 10, spacing, frng, (float[]) { min, max });

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        printf(i == 0 ? "%f" : ", %f", numbers[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

This ensures that all the generated numbers are truly independent (as much as your rng allows).

If you were to generate numbers from a reduced range after picking a number, numbers at the extrema are more likely as they are less likely to be in the reduced range. Though this may be alright for your application and is probably going to be a lot faster.

Generating in a larger range and dividing is equivalent to generating in the smaller range, so it doesn't solve the problem (Or you restrict yourself to integer multiples of `dx`, which is probably not what you want).

Comment: Thanks a lot..!!